# mongo driver not detecting primary node in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a sharded mongo set up on AWS with 3 nodes out of which 2 are secondary and 1 primary.
When I try to connect to the same through rails it does not seem that primary is detected and queries timeout.

```
$mg = Mongo::MongoShardedClient.from_uri("mongodb://mongo-n1.abc.com:27017,mongo-n2.abc.com:27017,mongo-n3.abc.com:27017/testdb", w: 0, :read => :primary).db
```

Note that if however I change the order of mongo nodes in above (i.e. make n3 the first one in the connection string it works because n3 is primary.

Is there any way that can be detected automatically by driver ?

Comment: add `?replicaSet=<your_set_name>` to the URI. Most drivers "presume" a seed list means you are connecting to a replica set. But I'm not certain that behavior is actually to "spec". You **"should"** really be specifying the replica set name on such connections.

Comment: You should also be able to add `:replica_set => <your_set_name>` in the options as well. One or the other though.

Comment: Also beware of the big "gotcha". Any FQDN specified in the "replica set configuration" needs to be the **public available address** or at least visible by the clients that connect to it. If you just used "server visible names", then the client attempts to use those when it reads the configuration from the connected node, and if it cannot reach them then it's not a replica set connection and simply a connection to a node.

Comment: hmm, it seems ti be ignoring replica_set param either through options or in uri.

Comment: Proven how? The only way you can really prove this is to connect to a replica set and bring down nodes. Are basically keep starting a small program with the connection string until there is only one node left. Without any other options, a correctly configured connection will refuse if there is no "PRIMARY" left in the set. If you still can connect, then you did it wrong. The driver has "wide" usage. So it works for everyone else, so it's far more likely you are wrong and not the driver. Provide a test case that proves your point of view and we'll look